# Ler blocos de tags XML com base em uma busca

Tags: python, arquivo, io

Tenho uma pasta onde são guardados os logs de inserção no banco de dados. Os arquivos de log seguem essa estrutura:

```
             <item xsi:type="tns:StatusResultReport">
                <id xsi:type="xsd:int">1569692</id>
                <placa xsi:type="xsd:string">XXX</placa>
                <ocorrencia_id xsi:type="xsd:string">00</ocorrencia_id>
                <msg xsi:type="xsd:string">Adicionado</msg>
                <sucesso xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</sucesso>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="tns:StatusResultReport">
                <placa xsi:type="xsd:string">XXX</placa>
                <ocorrencia_id xsi:type="xsd:string">00</ocorrencia_id>
                <msg xsi:type="xsd:string">Não encontrado</msg>
                <sucesso xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</sucesso>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="tns:StatusResultReport">
                <id xsi:type="xsd:int">1569693</id>
                <placa xsi:type="xsd:string">XXX</placa>
                <ocorrencia_id xsi:type="xsd:string">00</ocorrencia_id>
                <msg xsi:type="xsd:string">Adicionado</msg>
                <sucesso xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</sucesso>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="tns:StatusResultReport">
                <id xsi:type="xsd:int">1569694</id>
                <placa xsi:type="xsd:string">XXX</placa>
                <ocorrencia_id xsi:type="xsd:string">00</ocorrencia_id>
                <msg xsi:type="xsd:string">Adicionado</msg>
                <sucesso xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</sucesso>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="tns:StatusResultReport">
                <id xsi:type="xsd:int">1569695</id>
                <placa xsi:type="xsd:string">XXX</placa>
                <ocorrencia_id xsi:type="xsd:string">00</ocorrencia_id>
                <msg xsi:type="xsd:string">Adicionado</msg>
                <sucesso xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</sucesso>
            </item>
```

Atualmente, eu sei que um registro foi inserido quando a tag `sucesso` vem com o valor `true`, e sei que teve falha quando o valor é `false`.

O que quero fazer é através de um programa Python, ler esses arquivos e extrair os blocos `<item></item>` que contenham sucesso=`false`

Tentei com o código abaixo, mas ele extrai apenas a linha `false`

```
search = 'false'

def check():
    datafile = open('C:\\TESTE\\LCL_20170420_30052.67.XML')
    for line in datafile:
        if search in line:
            found = True
            print(line)
            break
        else:
            found = False
    return found


check()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) para navegar entre as tags do seu arquivo XML.

Poderia utilizar outras bibliotecas também, como a [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), [`minidom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) ou a [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/), por exemplo.

**Código:**

```
s = '''
<item xsi:type="tns:StatusResultReport">
    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">1569692</id>
    <placa xsi:type="xsd:string">XXX</placa>
    <ocorrencia_id xsi:type="xsd:string">00</ocorrencia_id>
    <msg xsi:type="xsd:string">Adicionado</msg>
    <sucesso xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</sucesso>
</item>
<item xsi:type="tns:StatusResultReport">
    <placa xsi:type="xsd:string">XXX</placa>
    <ocorrencia_id xsi:type="xsd:string">00</ocorrencia_id>
    <msg xsi:type="xsd:string">Não encontrado</msg>
    <sucesso xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</sucesso>
</item>
<item xsi:type="tns:StatusResultReport">
    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">1569693</id>
    <placa xsi:type="xsd:string">XXX</placa>
    <ocorrencia_id xsi:type="xsd:string">00</ocorrencia_id>
    <msg xsi:type="xsd:string">Adicionado</msg>
    <sucesso xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</sucesso>
</item>
<item xsi:type="tns:StatusResultReport">
    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">1569694</id>
    <placa xsi:type="xsd:string">XXX</placa>
    <ocorrencia_id xsi:type="xsd:string">00</ocorrencia_id>
    <msg xsi:type="xsd:string">Adicionado</msg>
    <sucesso xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</sucesso>
</item>
<item xsi:type="tns:StatusResultReport">
    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">1569695</id>
    <placa xsi:type="xsd:string">XXX</placa>
    <ocorrencia_id xsi:type="xsd:string">00</ocorrencia_id>
    <msg xsi:type="xsd:string">Adicionado</msg>
    <sucesso xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</sucesso>
</item>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')

item_tags = soup.find_all('item')

for item in item_tags:
    if item.sucesso.text == 'true':
        print(item)
        print('='*5)
```

**Output:**

```
<item xsi:type="tns:StatusResultReport">
<id xsi:type="xsd:int">1569692</id>
<placa xsi:type="xsd:string">XXX</placa>
<ocorrencia_id xsi:type="xsd:string">00</ocorrencia_id>
<msg xsi:type="xsd:string">Adicionado</msg>
<sucesso xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</sucesso>
</item>
=====
<item xsi:type="tns:StatusResultReport">
<id xsi:type="xsd:int">1569693</id>
<placa xsi:type="xsd:string">XXX</placa>
<ocorrencia_id xsi:type="xsd:string">00</ocorrencia_id>
<msg xsi:type="xsd:string">Adicionado</msg>
<sucesso xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</sucesso>
</item>
=====
<item xsi:type="tns:StatusResultReport">
<id xsi:type="xsd:int">1569694</id>
<placa xsi:type="xsd:string">XXX</placa>
<ocorrencia_id xsi:type="xsd:string">00</ocorrencia_id>
<msg xsi:type="xsd:string">Adicionado</msg>
<sucesso xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</sucesso>
</item>
=====
<item xsi:type="tns:StatusResultReport">
<id xsi:type="xsd:int">1569695</id>
<placa xsi:type="xsd:string">XXX</placa>
<ocorrencia_id xsi:type="xsd:string">00</ocorrencia_id>
<msg xsi:type="xsd:string">Adicionado</msg>
<sucesso xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</sucesso>
</item>
=====
```

**Outros Exemplos:**

- [Exemplo c/ minidom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1912516/3846228)
- [Exemplo c/ ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1912483/3846228)

Comment: Pode me explicar o porque do *5 ? não entendi

Comment: Só coloquei p/ no output ele separar as tags `<item></item>` e facilitar a visualização e o entendimento do código.. A cada final de iteração do loop ele passa um "traço" de tamanho 5 e começa o outro item.